# How to install flaskext.mysql with yum/centos?

Tags: python, mysql, flask, centos, yum

While running a program, I get the error `ImportError: No module named flaskext.mysql`.  How can I fix this with yum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install `flaskext.mysql` using `pip`

`pip install flask-mysql`

If you don't have `pip` you can install that using the instructions here:
https://packaging.python.org/install_requirements_linux/#centos-rhel

Flask-MySQL Documentation:
http://flask-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/